# C++: Printing or cout a standard library container to console

Tags: c++, printing, cout, std

What's the C++ way to print or `cout` a C++ standard library container to the console, to view its contents?

On a separate note, why doesn't the C++ library actually overload the `<<` operator for you? Any history behind it?

Comment: Iterate through the elements and print each one?  Maybe you could show an example of what you're asking.

Comment: Are you printing objects which you want to get a specific value or are you printing simple data types?

Comment: You might try a [pretty printer](http://louisdx.github.io/cxx-prettyprint/)

Comment: There are quite a few similar existing questions, with requirements and answers at different levels of complexity and completeness... e.g. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4850473/pretty-print-c-stl-containers?lq=1

Comment: @RetiredNinja: I would just like a nice way to print objects out, similar to how you could `print list` or `print set` in python. No order required.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The simplest way is to use the range-based for statement. For example

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include <vector>
#include <iterator>

template <class Container>
std::ostream & display( const Container &container, 
                        const char *s = " ",
                        std::ostream &os = std::cout )
{
    for ( const auto &value : container )
    {
        os << value << s;
    }

    return os;
}

int main()
{
    int a[] = { 0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9 };
    std::vector<int> v( std::begin( a ), std::end( a ) );

    display( a, "; " );
    std::cout << std::endl;

    display( v );
    std::cout << std::endl;

    return 0;
}
```

The program output is

```
0; 1; 2; 3; 4; 5; 6; 7; 8; 9; 
0 1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9
```

However a more flexibale approach will be to use standard algorithm `std::copy`. In this case you can set the displayed range yourself and use reverse iterators. 
Also you can write the function such a way that it would get additional information.

> why doesn't the C++ library actually overload the << operator for you?

Because any user can use his own approach to output a container as you can see from the output of my demonstrative program. In fact a container is a user-defined class and it is the user who should overload operator <<. There is  exceptions for std::string and std::bitset but strings and bitsets are outputed as one entity without intermediate separates similarly to fundamental types.

Comment: I feel like C++ should provide some standard implementations for `operator<<`. Python at least does this for its standard data structures.

Answer (score 4):

Overloading the `operator<<` for `ostream` is the way to go. Here's one possibility:

```
template <class container>
std::ostream& operator<<(std::ostream& os, const container& c)
{
    std::copy(c.begin(),
              c.end(),
              std::ostream_iterator<typename container::value_type>(os, " "));
    return os;
}
```

Then you can simply write:

```
std::cout << SomeContainer << std::endl;
```

Here are some other actually really nice solutions: [Pretty-print C++ STL containers](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4850473/pretty-print-c-stl-containers)

Answer (score 0):

For variety, make an adaptor, something like

```
template< typename T >
struct SequencePrinter
{
    const T& t;
    // ...
};
template< typename T >
SequencePrinter<T> sequence_printer(const T&);
template< typename T >
ostream& operator<<(ostream&, SequencePrinter<T>);
int main() {
    vector<int> v;
    // ...
    cout << sequence_printer(v) << endl;
}
```

This allows the usual `<<` notation, but doesn't try to force a particular choice of what `<<` should mean with a sequence. It could, of course, be made fairly configurable too.